# How to disable button using jquery in materialize css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am using jquery to disable a button in materialize css. According to documentation [here](http://materializecss.com/buttons.html), the way to disable button is simply by adding a class named 'disabled'.I think by simply add class 'disabled', the button will automatically disabled, but it is not. Here is my code:

html:

```
<button id='submit-btn' class="btn waves-effect waves-light submit red" type="button" name="action">
```

jquery:

```
$('#submit-btn').off().on('click', function(){
    $('#submit-btn').addClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: That is only CSS. If you add JS or HTML action you have to disbale it manually

Comment: @joyBlanks is right, that will be just `css` styling, to disable `events` etc, you will need to do it manually

Comment: Hmm, so, how to disable it with jquery, I try .prop('disabled', true), but still it won't disable the button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36174382/4763793

Comment: If you have an onclick attached to it. The onclick should do a check that if it hasClass disabled. If no then proceed else return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#submit-btn').removeClass("waves-effect waves-light submit").addClass('disabled');
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("waves-effect waves-light submit").addClass('disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id='submit-btn' class="btn waves-effect waves-light submit red" type="button" name="action">
```

Comment: The more stuff like this I run into, the more I regret working with MaterializeCSS. So frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems doesn't work with materialize css

Comment: Could you post the code, please? How exactly are you calling the routine to disable the button?

Comment: You'll want to wrap your code in $(function(){...}), it should work then

Answer (score 1):

To disable the button using javascript.

```
eleme.classList.add('disabled');
```

To enable the button using javascript.

```
elem.classList.remove('disabled');
```

**E.g:**

```
let btn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
btn.classList.add('disabled'); //This will disable the button
```

Answer (score 0):

to disable button you can use

```
$("#submit-btn").attr("disabled", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable which holds the button (say submitBtn), then add an event listener (say on DOMContentLoaded), then have the function disable the button with submitBtn.disabled = true;