# MaterializeCss link as button starts disabled, javascript won't enable

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, materialize

I've got a page using materializecss that starts with these link buttons disabled. I want to use JavaScript to enable them.

tried - changing the .class property to remove "disabled"
tried - changing the .disabled property to false

```
 <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
      <li><a class="waves-effect waves-yellow btn-flat white-text" href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=zapAdmin" disabled="true" >Zap Admin</a></li>
      <li><a class="waves-effect waves-yellow btn-flat white-text" href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=nzap" disabled="true">Create Zap</a></li>
      <li><a class="waves-effect waves-yellow btn-flat white-text" href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=reports" disabled="true" >Reports</a></li>
      <li><a class="waves-effect waves-yellow btn-flat white-text" href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=extra" disabled="true">EXTRA</a></li>
  </ul>


function refUser(access) {
  if (access == 'granted') {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs tabs-transparent")[0];
    var links = div.getElementsByTagName('a');
    console.log(links);
    for(i=0;i<links.length;i++){
      var link = links[i];
      link.disabled=false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try waiting until the dom has completely loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `waves-effect waves-yellow white-text` classes before add `disabled` class

Seems that a similar question was already asked. Check out and see if some answer works for you.

Visit [How to disable button using jquery in materialize css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174320/how-to-disable-button-using-jquery-in-materialize-css).

Comment: Thanks! This lead me to the correct answer.

Those who need to do the same - the above link shows how to do it with jquery, but with javascript you use this:
element.classList.remove('disabled')